# Using angular $scope in multiple templates

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am working on an angular app and I am running into a problem loading $scope into another page.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
function editorCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
   $scope.html = { content: '' };
   $scope.data = {
      name: ''
   }
   $scope.goToDoc = function() {
      $http.get('/doc/' + $scope.data.name).success(function(data) {
         $scope.html.content = JSON.stringify(data.html);
         $location.path('/docs/' + $scope.data.name);
      });
   }
}

// My app config
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .config(function($routeProvider) {
      .when('/editor', {
      controller: 'editorCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/app/partials/editor.html'
  })
  .when('/docs/:name', {
      controller: 'editorCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/app/partials/doc.html'
  })
      ...

// My doc Template
{{ html.content }}

// editor template
<input type="input" ng-model="data.name">
<button ng-click="goToDoc()">GOTO</button>
```

I am trying to do a request to my API and set the $scope.html.content to the returned data.  If I console the $scope.html.content I get the correct value, but it is not updating in my doc template.  How do I get $scope in my editorCtrl to update my doc template?  Or am I going about this in a totally wrong way?  Do I need to create a service to do this?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it work in a fiddle.  I am using node to make a backend API that I am calling to in the $http call.  Basically, I am making a call to get the data in the editorCtrl when the GOTO button is clicked.  I want to take that data and inject it into the doc template.  Is this possible?